# Apache httpd server redirect url with anchor tag(fragment id) in it

Tags: apache, redirect, httpd.conf

I'm setting up redirects in conf.d/ssl.conf of apache http server 2.2.34 for urls with anchor tag in it but it's not redirecting if the anchor tag is present in the target url of RewriteRule.

I have set of urls with different anchor tags in it and want to redirect  each to a new url, like
1)https://example.com/index.php#version-test -> test.example.com/test.php
2)https://example.com/index.php#version-beta -> beta.example.com/beta.php

Here is the httpd.conf code which is not redirecting,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule "^/index.php#version-test" "test.example.com/test.php" [NE,R=301,L]
RewriteRule "^/index.php#version-beta" "beta.example.com/beta.php" [NE,R=301,L]
```

howerver if i remove anchor tag in it

> RewriteRule "^/index.php" "test.example.com/test.php" [NE,R=301,L]

its redirecting properly to test.example.com/test.php.

is there any special case on how to handle urls with anchor tag in it? or am i missing something here?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the duplicate questions. I was not able to see that questions in stackoverflow search before, due to various terms used for anchor tag. I find it hard to belive that httpd server dosen't support this type of url redirections.